# When are commutative, finite-dimensional complex algebras isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ both be associative, commutative, finite-dimensional, complex algebras of dimension $n$, e.g. over $\Bbb C$.

What are some necessary and sufficient conditions for $A$ and $B$ to be isomorphic?

In particular, I'm interested in the situation where $A$ and $B$ have zero divisors, but both have *no* nilpotent elements. Is this sufficient to declare $A$ and $B$ isomorphic?

Two examples of such algebras are the pointwise multiplication on $\Bbb C^n$, and the convolution algebra on $\Bbb C^n$. These are isomorphic via the discrete Fourier transform. Are all complex algebras of the same dimension, which don't have nilpotent elements, isomorphic to these two?

Comment: If $\dim A>1$, then $A$ must have zero divisors, since otherwise $A$ would be a field (multiplication by any nonzero $a\in A$ is injective and hence surjective since $A$ is finite-dimensional) and thus a nontrivial finite extension of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $A$ and $B$ have no (nonzero) nilpotent elements, then $A\cong B$.  To prove this, note that $A$ is artinian and hence is a product of local artinian rings $A_i$.  A local artinian ring with no nilpotents is a field, so each $A_i$ is a field.  But each $A_i$ is then a finite extension of $\mathbb{C}$, and the only such extension is $\mathbb{C}$ itself.  So $A$ is a product of copies of $\mathbb{C}$, and hence $A\cong \mathbb{C}^n$.  The same is true of $B$, so $A\cong B$.

Comment: More generally, one can use the fact that the Jacobson Radical of an artinian ring is nilpotent and the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem to conclude that an artinian ring has no nilpotent elements if and only if it is a product of division rings.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I had thought similar reasoning would state that for $N$-dimensional finite-dimensional real algebras, everything is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb C^m$, for some $n,m$ such that $n+2m=N$. I think this argument then shows that.

Comment: @Mike: yes. One way to say this is that for commutative fd algebras, having no nonzero nilpotents is equivalent to being semisimple. Then you can use the classification of these.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. How does this change if you do add nilpotents? I would assume it depends on the order of the nilpotent, but is there any general classification of these?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: As far as I know there's no nice classification if you allow nilpotents (though you can still reduce to the case that $A$ is local as above).  If $A$ is local with maximal ideal $M$ and you pick generators $x_1,\dots,x_n$ for $M$, then you can identify $A$ with $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ where $I$ is an ideal that contains $(x_1,\dots,x_n)^k$ for some $k$.  But my understanding is that when $k$ and $n$ are large, such ideals are hard to classify.

Comment: Ah, alright. Makes sense. These turned out to be much less interesting than I expected! I was also going to ask about $\Bbb Z$-algebras, but then this is equivalent to just asking about commutative rings in general. Is there any sort of nice classification of general commutative rings without nilpotents?

Comment: No, general commutative rings without nilpotents are waaay too broad to classify--the finite-dimensional restriction in your original question makes a huge difference.

Comment: Yes, sorry, still looking for that - so finite-dimensional, commutative, nilpotent-free $\Bbb Z$-algebras...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "finite-dimensional" when you're not over a field.  But in general, any commutative artinian ring without nilpotents is a finite product of fields, by essentially the argument I gave.