# When is a semiprime finitely generated, reduced/semiprime $\Bbb Z$-algebras a product of integral domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269163/when-are-commutative-finite-dimensional-complex-algebras-isomorphic/2269170#2269170) question, I asked about commutative finite-dimensional $\Bbb C$-algebras without nilpotents. Turns out that all such algebras are isomorphic to $\Bbb C$^n.

How does this classification change if we look at commutative finite-dimensional $\Bbb Z$-algebras instead? These can also be thought of as finite-dimensional semiprime rings, or as reduced rings, which are equivalent in the commutative case.

All of the examples I've looked at so far seem to be a product of integral domains - things like $\Bbb Z$, finite fields $GF(p^n)$'s, or ring extensions such as $\Bbb Z[i]$. This leads to the following conjecture:

**Is every finitely generated commutative semiprime $\Bbb Z$-algebra a direct product of integral domains?**

If not, then in general, is every finite-dimensional commutative semiprime ring a direct product of *something*? If so, what?

**EDIT:** [this page](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/commalg/nilradical.html) says that every finite-dimensional commutative semiprime ring injects into a direct product of integral domains, e.g. it is a "subdirect product". The question is now whether or not this reduces to a full direct product in the finitely generated case.

Comment: Do you require a multiplicative identity? ​ Do you mean finitely-generated instead of finite-dimensional? ​ If no to the latter, then how do you define whether-or-not a $\big[\mathbb{Z}$-algebra whose additive group has non-zero torsion elements$\big]$ is finite-dimensional? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes, with multiplicative identity, and I do mean finitely generated. Will edit the question for clarity.

Comment: $ \mathbf Z[\sqrt{-1}] $ (or more generally any number ring) is a finite dimensional commutative semiprime ring which is not of the form you describe.

Comment: Good catch. I think I'm going to simplify the conjecture to - every semiprime/reduced ring is a product of integral domains. Will edit.

Comment: By finitely generated you mean finitely generated as a module, rather than as an algebra?

Comment: @EricWofsey: yes, isomorphic as modules. Basically, I'm looking at $\Bbb Z$-modules of finite dimension. An example would include the convolution algebra with "vectors" having only integer coefficients. But [this page](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/commalg/nilradical.html) here says that all semisimple rings (not just finitely generated ones) are isomorphic to a subdirect product of integral domains, so now the question is whether this becomes a full direct product in the finitely generated case (or what a counterexample would be if not).

Comment: Hah, I was just seconds too slow with the same counterexample. Perhaps you are interested in a slightly different theorem: commutative reduced rings are exactly subdirect products of integral domains. You just use the natural injection into the product of quotients by prime ideals.

Comment: @rschweib: I guess the question is, under what conditions are they exactly direct products?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia (Use tab completion to avoid misspelling usernames on notifications.) I thought a bit about that myself, and I think the answer is not clear. When $R$ is finitely cogenerated, that lets you cut it down to a injection into finitely many factors, but you still need some special conditions to try to make it an isomorphism. For example, if prime ideals are maximal, then you're guaranteed surjectivity by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Unfortunately at this juncture we have walked ourselves down to commutative semisimple rings, a (comparatively) small class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ring $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$.  This ring is reduced and not a domain, since $(x+1)(x-1)=0$.  However, it has no nontrivial idempotents (as you can check by either a direct computation or by the geometric argument below), so it cannot be a product of domains either.

Geometrically, $\operatorname{Spec} A$ has two irreducible components, one where $x=1$ and another where $x=-1$.  However, these components intersect when $2=0$ (i.e., at the maximal ideal $(2,x-1)=(2,x+1)$), so $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is still connected (and thus $A$ is not a product of rings in any nontrivial way).  You can think of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ as an arithmetic version of two lines which cross at a point.

Comment: Ah, OK. I had a comment about this being related to the split-complex numbers, but I see where I went wrong now. You *would* get idempotents, but you can't express $\frac{1+x}{2}$ with integer coefficients. So this is good, thanks.